# How to define multivariate normal distribution for three or more random variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory

If $X,Y,Z$ are three random variables with normal distribution, how can we define the joint distribution of $(X,Y,Z)$? Can we define a similar covariance tensor $\Sigma=Cov(X,Y,Z) = E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])(Z-E[Z])]$?

Notice that knowing only the joint distribution of any two is not sufficient to know the joint distribution. We need the know the information of such a tensor $\Sigma$.

My question comes from in the following problem. Consider $\Sigma$ to be symmetric, $\Sigma_{ijk} = \Sigma_{ikj}=\Sigma_{jik}=\Sigma_{jki}=\Sigma_{kij}=\Sigma_{kji}$.

If 
$$\partial_t \Sigma_{ijk} + \Sigma_{sjk} \partial_{x_s} u_i  +\Sigma_{isk} \partial_{x_s} u_j +\Sigma_{ijs} \partial_{x_s} u_k = 0, $$
can we find a function $f=f(\Sigma)$ such that 
$$\partial_t f + \partial_{x_s} u_s = 0$$
Here we use that Einstein summation notation. And for $\sigma$ being a matrix, this is easy. Since if $\partial_t \sigma_{ij} + \sigma_{sj} \partial_{x_s} u_i+\sigma_{is} \partial_{x_s} u_j=0$, we have $f(\sigma)=\ln \det \sigma$ satisfying $f_t + 2 \nabla \cdot u = 0$.

These two questions are related, which I will not show here.

Comment: I take it that an issue is that it is unknown if $(X,Y,Z)$ has a multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: It is also worth noting that with three random variables $X, Y, Z$, the object $E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)(Z-\mu_Z)]$ is a scalar. If instead there were four or more variables, say $X_i : i = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$, then a three-indexed tensor might make more sense: $\Sigma_{i,j,k} = E[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)(X_k - \mu_k)]$.

Comment: $X$ is a vector here.

Comment: Ah OK. So, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ each individually have multivariate normal distributions, and you are considering the joint distribution of the collection of these random vectors.